# Android Facebook Login - App Disabled - URL Compliance

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I've got this alert from fb:

> Your app xxx(AppId: xxx) doesn't fully comply with
>   our Platform Policies. Since we're striving to improve the Platform
>   experience, your app has been deactivated.
>
> Your app is violating Platform Policy 7.9: We or an independent
>   auditor acting on our behalf may audit your app, systems, and records
>   to ensure your use of Platform and data you receive from us is safe
>   and complies with our Terms, and that you've complied with our
>   requests and requests from people who use Facebook to delete user data
>   obtained through our Platform. If requested, you must provide us with
>   proof that your app complies with our terms.
>
> You can access the full list of our Platform Policies here:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/policy/.
>
> You can check your app dashboard to verify if the violating fields are
>   now compliant, otherwise you will receive an automated alert as soon
>   as we've detected that the fields are compliant.

What the hell do they want from me?? I all use the app for is to retrieve an ID to identify an user, I don't save anything else like name/email and so on, only the ID!

I've checked all the setting fields if there is any warning/alert but it all looks ok.

I have the developement mode because the app isn't published yet and the login still works on the device with my account.

However, when I use the device from someone else then I get this error:

```
{HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, subErrorCode: 33, errorType: GraphMethodException, errorMessage: Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'xxxx' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api}
```

It has to do with the restriction I guess?

the ID in `Object with ID 'xxxx'` is the app ID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue and I only went to **settings > basic** below **Dashboard** on my Facebook App and I checked **Add platform > Website > Site URL** and changed the value here to a correct URL because I had something like localhost and automatically I resolved my problem.

Comment: But it's correct by me. I have a new guess. Maybe it's because the android package name isn't correct because the app isn't published yet. I will see if that's the case. But if that's the case then I wonder why this warning/restriction didn't came up earlier

Comment: My assumption was correct, it was because the Android app wasn't published yet. After I published it and inserted the release hash for login the issue instantly resolved. Since your answer is close enough I'll accept

Comment: @Pikaboo I have the same issue. Can it be resolved without releasing this app?

Comment: Nope if it's the android package name then you must publish the app to solve it

Comment: @Pikaboo How did facebook not throw the error before when it was entered?

Comment: @Pikaboo the app is still under dev and not ready for release as it has to be tested

Comment: I was also surprised

Comment: Man I have a well-published app on playstore and correct package name and website address BUT STILL I GOT THIS ERROR WHAT TO DO?

Comment: My Website was not live probably this can the reason

Comment: Hi @Pikaboo, I got into the same problem now and already my app is live. In the Settings->Basic-> Android packages field, I have 4 packages (1 was a published app, and the other 3 are for a testing environment like Stage, internal testing, etc.). How can I resolve this without publish the app? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had received the same policy complain:
**Your app is violating Platform Policy 7.9**

But my solution was different than the accepted answer. Application dropped on development mode and when I click **Live** it shows me the error text.

I had published two google play applications that was using the same facebook app, the old one was unpublished but still exist on "
**Android >> Google Play Package Name**". I just removed the unpublished apps package name from there and the issue immediately resolved.

Comment: Hi @eerrzz, I got into the same problem now and already my app is live. In the Settings->Basic-> Android packages field, I have 4 packages (1 was a published app, and the other 3 are for a testing environment like Stage, internal testing, etc.). How can I resolve this without publish the app?

Answer (score 0):

The another possible way to solve this without publishing the IOS and Android apps is to remove the IOS and Android platform from the app which is in live mode.

You can create  another app  keep it in development mode and add IOS , Android in that so these can be tested before you have to publish.