# Login with Facebook suddenly stopped in react-native app

Tags: react-native, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I have a react-native app that uses Facebook APIs to let the user log into the app. Everything was working fine until on 22nd Feb 2023 logging in with Facebook stopped working.

I have not made any changes in my app's front-end as well as back-end but still, my app is getting restricted.

Whenever I raise the appeal, Facebook replies with "this case has been closed" but still Facebook doesn't allow users to log on to my app.

- I have tried the following suggestions:-

1] [https://stackoverflow.com/a/62239216](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

2] On the 'meta for developers' forum, one guy suggested asking for a detailed explanation to Facebook.

- I have also replied to facebook's mail asking for a detailed explanation of the policy violation.

1] Broken Facebook integration (e.g. broken share, like, or comment functionality)

2] Broken user experience in the app (e.g. app has broken links or user interface failures)Graph API access for  was disable

Comment: please debug your app. and read about the error. also share what your have tried.